# javascript for bank loan calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I want to insert a bank loan calculator for the webpage, i had found the javascript.
I had modify the javascript but it unable to function.

this is where i found the javascript

https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Monthly-Payment-Loan-Calculator-Form-Programming-Tutorial

here is my script

```
function computeLoan(){
    var amount = document.getElementById('pricerange').value;
    var years = document.getElementById('bankloan').value;
    var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
    var loan = (amount * 90) / 100;
    var months = years * 12;
    var interest = (loan * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;
    var payment = ((loan / months) + interest).toFixed(2);
    payment = payment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById('installment').innerhtml = payment;
}

<div>Loan Amount: $ 
    <select id="pricerange" onchange="computeLoan()">
        <option value="0" >Select an option</option>
        <option value="200000">200k</option>
        <option value="300000">300k</option>
        <option value="400000">400k</option>
        <option value="500000">500k</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>Year:
<select id="bankloan" onchange="computeLoan()">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option value="001">1</option>
    <option value="002">2</option>
    <option value="003">3</option>
    <option value="004">4</option>
    <option value="005">5</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>Interest Rate: <input id="interest_rate" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="10" step=".1" onchange="computeLoan()">%</div>
<div>Installment monthly
<input id="installment" type="text">
</div>
```

The calculation is

payment = (90% amount of loan / month)  + ((90% amount of loan * 4.2% of interest rate)/month)

The result of the calculation will be shown in the textbox with Id installment.

Thanks

Comment: "it unable to function": have you check the console for errors? What is your expected output?

Comment: the output is the monthly payment that the user has to pay, this is the calculation: (90% amount of loan / month) + ((90% amount of loan * 4.2% of interest rate)/month) @Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an `<input>` element to display the value calculated, but attempting to set that using `.innerHTML`. The example you copied had the result displayed in an `<h2>` element, which does have a useful `innerHTML` property.

You should use `.value` to display your result:

```
document.getElementById('installment').value = payment;
```

[Note that until both values are set the result is `NaN` -- you may need some validation in there too.]